# Only change single elements style from many similar class selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this following code which changes style of elements through clicking each of it.
from `border:1px solid #dedede` to `2px solid #f60000`.

```
<script>
var ckStyle = document.getElementsByClassName("cls");
for (var i = 0; i < ckStyle.length; i++) {
    ckStyle[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.style.border = "2px solid #f60000"; 
        }, false);
    }  
</script>
```

I try like this below, but not working:

```
<script>
var ckStyle = document.getElementsByClassName("cls");
for (var i = 0; i < ckStyle.length; i++) {
    ckStyle[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.style.border = "2px solid #f60000"; 
        }, false);
    return(
        this.style.border = "1px solid #dedede"; 
      );
    }  
</script>
```

**Default style in CSS:**

```
<style>
.cls{border:1px solid #dedede;}
</style>
```

**Here's The HTML:**

```
                <div class="cCont1">
                    <ul class='wr'>
                        <li class='cls color1'>Kuning</li>
                        <li class='cls color2'>Putih</li>
                        <li class='cls color3'>Hijau</li>
                        <li class='cls color4'>Biru</li>    
                        <li class='cls color5'>-</li>         
                        <li class='cls color6'>-</li>  
                        <li class='cls color7'>-</li>  
                        <li class='cls color8'>-</li>  
                        <li class='cls color9'>-</li>  
                        <li class='cls color10'>-</li>                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="cCont2">
                    <ul class='wr'>
                        <li class='cls color1'>Biru</li>
                        <li class='cls color2'>Hitam</li>
                        <li class='cls color3'>Putih</li>
                        <li class='cls color4'>Merah</li>
                        <li class='cls color5'>Coklat</li>
                        <li class='cls color6'>Abu-abu</li>   
                        <li class='cls color7'>-</li>  
                        <li class='cls color8'>-</li>  
                        <li class='cls color9'>-</li>  
                        <li class='cls color10'>-</li>                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

When I click `color1` in, say, `cCont2` the style of the `cls` element will be like `2px solid #f60000`. Then I click other element (e.g. `color2`) and again the style change as in `color1`.

**What I want is:** when I click `color1` and `color2`, only one element will be *styled*.
On the other hand, when I click `color1` and soon after that I click `color2` the style will change in `color2` and `color1` turn into *the default* as in CSS above.

Style only works on one element. And, previous element turns into the default.